# error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ target: { value: string; }; }'

Tags: javascript, angular, events, angular-event-emitter

I am getting an error while building angular app.

**HTML Template**

```
  <mat-form-field *ngIf="requested">
    <input
      matInput
      (input)="sendingAccesscode($event)"
      placeholder="{{ 'CODE_LABEL' | i18next }}"
      name="accesscode"
      formControlName="accesscode"
      minlength="6"
      required
    />
  </mat-form-field>
```

**TypeScript**

```
  sendingAccesscode(event: { target: { value: string }}) {
    if (event.target?.value.length >= 6) {
      this.accessCode.emit(event.target.value);
    }
  }
```

I am getting the following error:

````
error TS2345: 
Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ target: { value: string; }; }'.
  Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
    Type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to type '{ value: string; }'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type '{ value: string; }'.

13       (input)="sendingAccesscode($event)"
                                    ~~~~~~```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about setting it to the type `Event` this will fix your issue!

you can also use `InputEvent`

```
sendingAccesscode(event: Event) {
    const value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    if (value && value.length >= 6) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-nt41c8)

Comment: @shubham_agrawal
 great!

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to [Angular strict mode](https://angular.io/guide/strict-mode) is enabled. In strict mode Angular make sure the typing on template types correctly infer on what have been called on TS side.

Over here typescript cannot determine what is going on when the `target` object is evaluated in destructing `{ target: { value: string }}`. Thus you have to first convert objects to relevant `Type` over here to infer the appropriate type `HTMLInputElement`. Then rest of things are sorted on typescript side.

```
const value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
```